# Visual studio 2013 Store menu items are disabled for targeted application from 8.0 to 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-phone-8.1

first I have an application for windows mobile 8.0, then I want to upgrade it for windows 8.1
I used  Visual studio 2013 to oarget windows phone to windows phone 8.1 , result windows sliverlight 8.1.
the problem all the item in Store Menu are disabled, such as Create App Package... etc

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing Windows Phone 8.1 runtime and Silverlight applications.

Windows Phone 8.1 runtime will have those menus, Silverlight won't.

See Rob's detailed explanation here: [MSDN blog: Why can’t I create an app package?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wsdevsol/archive/2014/08/07/why-can-t-i-create-an-app-package-windows-phone-xap-vs-appx.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

To build on Chubosaurus's answer, the following project types in Visual Studio use the following runtimes.

- "Windows Phone 8.0" - Silverlight
- "Windows Phone 8.1" - WinRT
- "Windows Phone Silverlight 8.1" - Silverlight

For this reason Visual Studio currently has no upgrade path from "Windows Phone 8.0" to "Windows Phone 8.1", which causes a lot of dev confusion.